# In vis-network how to disable color change when selected or onmouseover

Tags: highlight, onmouseover, selected, visnetwork

When selecting a node or onmouseover background and border color change. Background is set to default #D2E5FF. I do not want it changes and need to disable this feature.

I know using 
`color: {highlight: { border: 'red', background: 'yellow' }},` 
in options I can set a color but this does not fix my problem as each of the nodes has its own color.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no way to forbid vis to highlight a selected node.
But in your click handler you can unselect the node very easily:

```
network.selectNodes([])
```